# Display condition in CSS

Tags: html, css, conditional-statements

I want to create a menu button for my responsive design.
I want to display the menu when the user has clicked on the button, and hide it when he has clicked back.

My Html code is the following:

```
<!-- Invisible checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" class="menu_hidden_checkbox" id="show_menu" role="button" />

<!-- Menu button -->
<label for="show_menu" class="btn btn-navbar"><i class="icon-align-justify"></i></label>
```

The associated CSS code I use is:

```
.menu_hidden_checkbox{border:0;clip:rect(0 0 0 0);height:1px;width:1px;margin:-1px;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:absolute;} */
.menu_hidden_checkbox:checked +.left-menu{display:block;}
```

The above code isn't working at all. When the checkbox is checked, nothing happens.

Did I make something wrong?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P8DJZ/ (Expand the row to see full screen/smartphone mode)

Comment: Can you put the code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hello. I've edited my question with the jsfiddle link.

Comment: The + operator in CSS is for adjacent siblings. left_menu is not adjacent to the hidden checkbox.

Comment: If put the hidden checkbox just before my left-menu: http://jsfiddle.net/P8DJZ/1/ But it's still not working.

Comment: Hm, then I'm afraid something else in your fiddle is messing things up. When I remove everything except the checkbox and the left-menu div, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/P8DJZ/3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can it be linked to the media parts ? `@media (max-width:480px)` for example ?

Comment: Problem solved. I forgot to remove `.navbar` from this line `.navbar .menu_hidden_checkbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Put your switch button everywhere you want to:

```
<label for="show_hide">Click here to hide/show the div</label>
```

Put this code just before the div you want to show/hide:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden_checkbox" id="show_hide" />
```

For example, if you want to hide this div, just do something like that:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden_checkbox" id="show_hide" />
<div class="hidden_div">
    Your hidden content will be there.
</div>
```

Then in your CSS file, add the following code:

```
.hidden_checkbox{border:0;clip:rect(0 0 0 0);height:1px;width:1px;margin:-1px;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:absolute;}
.hidden_div{display:none;}
.hidden_checkbox:checked + .hidden_div{display:block;}
```

The first line will hide the checkbox so the user will only be able to use your switch button and not directly the checkbox. The second line will hide your `div`.
The third and last line is a condition that will change your div display to `block` when and only when the `hidden_checkbox` is checked.

Basically, when the user will click on the switch button, the hidden checkbox will be checked and the `hidden_div` will appear. If he clicks once more on the button, the `hidden_div` should disapear.

I hope this could help someone.